# nested flexbox is not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I'm a flexbox beginner. I'm trying to implement a flexbox with different parameters into an already existing flexbox. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/xq4g3ruz/) is what I got so far. This is what I'm trying to do :

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #ffeead;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container>div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid #ffcc5c;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.element {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #edeeee;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin: 5px 0px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #edeeee;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.ads {}

.ads_element {
  width: calc(25% - 5px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>

  <div class="ads">
    <div class="ads_element"></div>
    <div class="ads_element"></div>
    <div class="ads_element"></div>
    <div class="ads_element"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without *nesting* the flexboxes - just adjust the `width` and `margin` of the `ads_element` - see demo below:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #ffeead;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container>div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid #ffcc5c;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.element {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #edeeee;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin: 5px 0px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #edeeee;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.ads_element {
  width: calc(25% - 15px); /* CHANGED */
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent !important; /* CHANGED */
  /* ADDED BELOW */
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <!-- <div class="ads"> -->
  <div class="ads_element"></div>
  <div class="ads_element"></div>
  <div class="ads_element"></div>
  <div class="ads_element"></div>
  <!-- </div> -->
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to change your markup, you can just make the `ads` a flexbox too - see demo below:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #ffeead;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container>div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid #ffcc5c;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.element {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #edeeee;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin: 5px 0px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #edeeee;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.ads { /* ADDED */
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent !important;
  
}

.ads_element {
  width: calc(25% - 5px);
  height: 100px;
  /* background-color: green; */
  /* ADDED BELOW */
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="ads">
    <div class="ads_element"></div>
    <div class="ads_element"></div>
    <div class="ads_element"></div>
    <div class="ads_element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need set the width and height of `ads`, otherwise this tag and all inside it will have 0 width and 0 height by default

```
.ads
{
    width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.ads_element
{
    width: calc(25% - 5px);
    height: 100px;
    background-color:green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

append it in your code for see the result

Answer (score 1):

I filled in the css properties of ads class

```
.ads
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Check the working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/L5egv0ah/1/

Answer (score 1):

Changes css of `.ads` and `.ads_element` below using display:flex and width:100% and background-color overwrite

```css
html, body 
{
  background-color: #ffeead;
  margin: 10px;
}
.container > div:nth-child(even) 
{
  background-color: red;
}

.container > div:nth-child(odd) 
{
  background-color: blue;
}
.container
{
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: auto;
 border: 5px solid #ffcc5c;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.element
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #edeeee;
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
    margin: 5px 0px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #edeeee;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.container > div:nth-child(odd).ads
{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.ads_element
{
 width: calc(25% - 5px);
 height: 200px;
 border:3px solid red;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>

 <div class="ads"> 
  <div class="ads_element"></div>
  <div class="ads_element"></div>
  <div class="ads_element"></div>
  <div class="ads_element"></div> 
 </div>

    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element_row">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element_row">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="ads"> 
        <div class="ads_element"></div>
        <div class="ads_element"></div>
        <div class="ads_element"></div>
        <div class="ads_element"></div> 
    </div>
  <div class="element_row">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="element_row">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body 
{
  background-color: #ffeead;
  margin: 10px;
}
.container > .element_row > div:nth-child(even) 
{
  background-color: red;
}

.container > .element_row > div:nth-child(odd) 
{
  background-color: blue;
}
.container
{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid #ffcc5c;
    display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.element_row{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.element
{
    width: 49%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #edeeee;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #edeeee;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.ads
{
    display: flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.ads_element
{
  width: 22%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```